# How can I optimize my code for Swapping the array elements of given range of indexes with related element?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, optimization, array-algorithms

Consider an array of integers A having N elements in which each element has a one- to-one relation with another array element.

For each i, where 1≤i≤N there exists a 1−>1 relation between element i and element N−i+1

The Task is to perform following operations on this array which are as follows:

Given two integers (L,R) we have to swap each element in that range with its related element.(See Sample explanation below)

Sample Input

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
2
1 2
2 3
```

Sample Output

```
5 2 3 4 1
```

Explanation
For first query,we will swap 1 with 5 and 2 with 4.
Now the array becomes- 5 4 3 2 1

Similarly now ,for the second query we will swap 4 with 2 and 3 with itself.
So the final array will be 5 2 3 4 1

My Program goes like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProfessorAndOps {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=in.nextInt();//length of array
    int a[]=new int[n];//array declaration
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        //inputting array elements
        a[i]=in.nextInt();
    }
    int q=in.nextInt();//number of queries
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        int l=in.nextInt();//left limit
        int r=in.nextInt();//right limit
        //swapping while iterating over the given range of array elements:
        for(int j=l-1;j<=r-1;j++){
            int temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[n-j-1];
            a[n-j-1]=temp;
            }
        }
    //Printing the output array:
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(i!=n-1){
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }

    }

}
}
```

I could only come up with BruteForce solution. I'm pretty sure there will be some pre-processing step or some optimisation technique with l and r variables, whatever I could think of, giving me wrong answer. Please help me optimise this code. To be specific, I would need my code's time complexity to be reduced from O(N+ Q*(R-L)) to something like O(Q+N)

Comment: Better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @matt I need optimization technique, not the code review. so I thought of asking here. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: XOR swap is good one to look at, wikipedia has a great explanation, if you know how to work out a truth table, it is easy to understand (hint: no temp variable is involved using xor swap)

Comment: @Dummy swap will take only O(1) time. I'd need something that reduces the time complexity from O((q*(r-l))+ n) to something like O(q + n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `O(Q + N)` time, `O(N)` space algorithm. Imagine a list of the corresponding swap counts only for `L` and `R` over the elements (we'll use a negative number for the `R` counts). What if we maintained a virtual stack while traversing it? (By "virtual," I mean it's not a real stack, just an integer that bears some theoretical similarity.)

For example:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

O(Q) processing:

q [1,3]
1  9  8  7  5 ...  <- what would happen to the array
0  1  0 -1  0 <- counts (what we actually store)

q [2,4]
1  9  3  4  6 ...  <- what would happen to the array
0  1  1 -1 -1 <- counts (what we actually store)

O(N) traversal:

index 0 didn't move,                     no change, stack: 0
index 1 moved once,          odd count,  changed,   stack: 1
index 2 moved 2 (stack + 1), even count, no change, stack: 2
index 3 moved 2 (stack),     even count, no change, stack: 2 - 1
index 4 moved 1 (stack),     odd count,  changed,   stack: 1 - 1
```

Comment: Could you please explain the thing you did in O(N) traversal?

Comment: @sbk sure! Do you understand why the odd/even count tells us if the element has changed after all the queries have run? Next, try to think how this would work with only *one* query: the elements that are assessed after the stack is positive will be counted as affected by the query. The stack is made positive by the L count stored. Then the R count stored subtracts that number from the stack so the next elements are assessed correctly as not being affected by this particular query.

Comment: @sbk after that, try to think how that addition and subtraction from the "stack" would affect the assessed elements if there were two queries that overlapped in a section: only some elements would be affected by both queries - how do you tell which? The subtraction from the stack signifies the boundary of a query, so the elements assessed after that subtraction only have the count of the query/s for which we did not yet reach the R count stored. Makes sense?

Comment: @גלעדברקן is this what you call a "Counting sort" algorithm?

Comment: @גלעדברקן did you mean "we have to maintain an auxiliary count array (positive count for l and negative count for r) over q queries, then traverse through the original array and swap only when we come across an odd count in the auxiliary array " ?

Comment: @Carlton I don't think so. What would it be sorting here?

Comment: @sbk right, keep an array of length N for the counts only of R and L at their corresponding indexes (I assume those would mostly be just 1 and -1 but if a particular query boundary is repeated, that particular count is incremented). Then in the final traversal, swap if the count is odd. (Not sure if this is an issue but you might also need to handle cases where the query extends over the halfway point, which would just mean modifying the query appropriately.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן It seems to be working for the particular example I've mentioned. And yeah, the beyond half way point also needs to be handled. wouldn't it be okay if I traverse till only half of the array(while swapping)?

Comment: @sbk traversing half seems correct since any query extending beyond the halfway point would convert to a shorter query ending before the halfway point.